# NextJS call to useMemo breaks the app - Invalid use of the Hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm working on a nextjs webapp , i'm having an issue with useMemo hook , its breaking the app .
When i use a static data array , no issues with this block of code , but when i try to load data using API , i'm having the error bellow .

Code :

```
function useCustomers(page, rowsPerPage, data) {
  return useMemo(() => {
    return applyPagination(data, page, rowsPerPage);
  }, [page, rowsPerPage]);
}

const useCustomerIds = (customers) => {
  return useMemo(() => {
    return customers.map((customer) => customer.id);
  }, [customers]);
};
```

Error :
[image: error stack trace]

Tried constant components , functional components
Tried putting the call to the use memo inside a useEffect , no issues with the use effect but useMemo still breaks

Comment: Where are you calling/using these custom hooks?

Comment: The use i created them in a customers page and called inside the component of that 
 same page